# KeyDown KeyEventArgs won't work

Tags: c#, keydown, hotkeys, registerhotkey, global-hotkey

I am trying to include HotKeys in my program but I don't know how to execute this code:

```
    private void Form_KeyDown(object data, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your VS and add an event in properties window.

Comment: How do you mean Hot keys? Like Ctrl+O for open or Alt+F for the file menu?

Comment: @Brandon yes just like that. especially in this case i am trying to set the INSERT key to stop my timer.

Comment: You just have to wire up the event. Then you can hit Insert, and your timer will stop. Do any keys enter that method?

Comment: @user3002135 - Is this a forms or console application?

Comment: @scheien its in forms

Answer (score 1):

Have you bound that event? Sounds like it is not wired up.

```
public Form()
{
    this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form_KeyDown);
}
```

You can bind event that way, or doubleclick the `KeyDown` event in the Properties window in Visual Studio.

If you choose the point and click way, the event will bound in the `Form.Designer.cs` file.

The complete code constructor and method would look like this:

```
public Form()
{
    this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form_KeyDown);
}

private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't know why but nothing happens when i press insert. maybe im to stupid for this :/

Comment: @user3002135 - you shold add the `this.KeyDown += ....` after the `InitializeComponents()` inside the constructor `public Form1() {...}`

Comment: i did but still wont work. it seems strange to me because i tried everything after all the instructions i have found and none of those worked...

Comment: @user3002135 - Can you update your question with code related to the wire up? Hard to tell what's wrong when you don't supply any more code than the method you are trying to call.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy&paste that code to your form (I find this usage easier)

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

*BTW: Don't forget to set true to **`KeyPreview`** property of the form.*

Comment: @user3002135 Of course it works. `This isn't working` doesn't give any info. How did you test it. Did you get an error? Where is your code?

Comment: well when i use the key it wont even enter the void.

Comment: @user3002135 You insist on not posting any more info other than saying *not working*. This is all I can do to help you with the available info.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment:

I'm not sure about the Insert key, but you're looking for Mnemonics. On your form, use the "&" character before the character you want to shortcut. For example, on any button, menu, label etc... that says "Open", change the text to "&Open" and it will do what you want.

Edit: Keep in mind, this binds the Alt+yourCharacter key combination, not just the single key. If you're looking specifically to do special keys (insert, F1 etc...) you will need to implement a solution from the other answers (I think @QtX's solution will do what you want)